# Getting container-ips inside docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-network

how can we run docker commands inside container with `docker-compose`?
Simply I want to get IP of some other network container.

I am running three container `va-server`, `db` and `api-server`. All the containers are in same `docker-network`

Here I am providing `docker-compose` file below:

```
version: "2.3"

services:
  va-server:
    container_name: va_server
    image: nitinroxx/facesense:amd64_2022.11.28 #facesense:alpha
    runtime: nvidia
    restart: always
    mem_limit: 4G
    networks:
    - perimeter-network
  db:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
    - "27017:27017"
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./facesense_db:/data/db
    command: [--auth]
    networks:
    - perimeter-network
  api-server:
    container_name: api_server
    image: nitinroxx/facesense:api_amd64_2022.11.28
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "465:465"
    restart: always
    networks:
    - perimeter-network
  
 
networks:
  perimeter-network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
      - gateway: 10.16.239.1
        subnet: 10.16.239.0/24
```

I have install `docker` inside the container which giving me below permission error:

`docker.errors.dockerexception: error while fetching server api version: ('connection aborted.', permissionerror(13, 'permission denied')`

Answer (score 1):

> ...inside [a] container [...] I want to get IP of some other network container....

Docker provides an internal DNS service that can resolve container names to their Docker-internal IP addresses.  From one of the containers you show, you could look up a host name like `db` to get the container's IP address; but in practice, this is a totally normal DNS name and all but the lowest-level networking interfaces can use those directly.

This does require that all of the containers involved be on the same Docker network.  Normally Compose sets this up automatically for you; in the file you show I might delete the `networks:` blocks and `container_name:` overrides in the name of simplicity.  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

In short:

1. You can probably use the Compose service names `va-server`, `db`, and `api-server` as host names without specifically knowing their IP addresses.
2. This probably means you never need to know the container IP addresses at all (they're usually unusable from outside Docker).
3. If you do need an IP address from inside a container, a DNS lookup can find it.

You can't usually run `docker` commands from inside containers.  You can't do this safely without making it possible for the container to take over the whole host.  There are usually better patterns that don't tie you to the Docker stack specifically.

Comment: I am pushing data into `db` from `va-server` for that I need ip address of `db` container to push data. I can't use network ip address like `192.168.0.xxx`. It will be kind of hardcoding. I am getting ip of `db` container using python's docker library. Is it good approach?

Comment: No.  Just use `db` as a host name directly in the `mongo` client and don't try to look up the IP address at all.

Comment: If I want to connect cloud db not local for that I have to use IP address.

Comment: You probably need its DNS name.  If it's on another host, you must use that host's IP address; if the database happens to be in a container, you can't tell that, and its internal IP address will be unreachable.